# Forwarding from one Gmail account to another ends up with apparently inconsistent 'deliveredto:'

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I am consolidating several Gmail accounts (leaf accounts) in on central account (e.g., `central@gmail.com`).

When faced with the choice between :

- Forwarding from each leaf account to the central account
- Checking mail for all leaf accounts from the central account

I took the first option, because it seems instantaneous (while checking happens roughly every our).

I am trying to forward to a different Gmail alias for each leaf account.

> Example: the first leaf account (`leaf1@gmail.com`) would forward to
>   `central+leaf1@gmail.com`.

I then use this forwarded to address as a criterion to create a filter for all mails forwarded from `leaf1@gmail.com`.

### The problem

I did a few tests, and it appears that the `Delivered-To:` field in the forwarded e-mail sometimes refers to the aliased address (`central+leaf1@gmail.com`), sometimes it does not (`central@gmail.com`).

Several tests were made, with different `From:` addresses, and with empty and non-empty mails, and I was not able to find the rule behind that. I am wondering if it is an inconsistency in Gmail's forwarding, or some deterministic rule?

Answer (score 1):

Try using *deliveredto* instead of *from*

For example you can use

> deliveredto:central+leaf1@gmail.com

to find emails forwarded from leaf1@gmail.com (as you pointed in your question, you used aliases as forwarding address, so you can make use of them)

Comment: There was a typo in my question : I was actually trying to filter on this "Delivered-To:" field; yet it appears to be inconsistent.

Comment: Did you use it exactly as "delivered-to"? Because you should use it without the dash character (as the example above)